# How do I tune the OpenALPR performance?

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I've tried OpenALPR on the demo website at http://www.openalpr.com/cloud-api.html using this image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e6SgMP1leghV9TZfrRZ1Ivb2VrgKwcR9 and it worked really well! I then downloaded and installed OpenALPR (2.2.4) on my Ubuntu system(16.04) and used the same image, but on my system the LPs are not recognized well at all, why this difference?

Thanks!

I have not changed the `/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf`

### Results

**openalpr website (http://www.openalpr.com/cloud-api.html)**
All three LPs visible are correctly recognized, interpreted & displayed:

- 15451BB
- FRJ7248
- DUS4092

**openalpr on my local system(same image)**:
Only the DUS4092 LP is recognized correctly (when not with the best confidence score either), the other ones are not recognized correctly at all!:

```
plate0: 10 results
    - F7Z3   confidence: 79.5944
    - F7Z43  confidence: 78.4474
    - F7Z4   confidence: 77.4031
    - 7Z43   confidence: 75.1095
    - F7ZS   confidence: 74.0161
    - F723   confidence: 73.8868
    - FR7Z3  confidence: 73.124
    - F7Z4S  confidence: 72.8691
    - F7243  confidence: 72.7398
    - FR7Z   confidence: 72.0797
plate1: 10 results
    - DUS409Z    confidence: 91.418
    - DUS4092    confidence: 89.1234
    - 0US409Z    confidence: 88.8466
    - 0US4092    confidence: 86.552
    - OUS409Z    confidence: 86.3993
    - QUS409Z    confidence: 86.1586
    - BUS409Z    confidence: 84.562
    - OUS4092    confidence: 84.1047
    - QUS4092    confidence: 83.864
    - DUS4O9Z    confidence: 83.5082
plate2: 6 results
    - 4535   confidence: 84.1997
    - 4585   confidence: 75.1175
    - 45S5   confidence: 69.7395
    - 4S35   confidence: 61.4974
    - 4S85   confidence: 52.4152
    - 4SS5   confidence: 47.0372
```

How can I tune up the system to match the performance on the demo site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opensource version is not so accurate. But you can use more training data to make the recognition much more precise.

Please refer this link for more details

[Detector training](https://github.com/openalpr/train-detector)

[Tesseract training](https://github.com/openalpr/train-ocr)